# Windows 8.1 Lenovo Y510p Hard Drive Issue?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, lenovo-laptop

I bought a Lenovo Y510p laptop just over a year ago and it is now running painfully slow (virus scans take 24 hours, chrome takes 60-120 seconds to open, booting can take up to 10 minutes before any program is able to be opened). I suspect it may be a hardware issue, when I first bought the computer within 3 weeks it stopped being able to boot (full black screen, no response). I sent it to lenovo support, they returned it working again (with all the files wiped) saying there was a "hard drive issue" no details. The same issue happened again 2 months later, same solution. Since the computer has been slow but it wasn't until the last 2 months that the computer got painfully slow.

I ran ATTO Disk Benchmark on the Toshiba MQ01ABD100 1tb hard drive and the speeds were under half of what articles that reviewed the hard drive when it was released reported. Should I replace the hard drive? Or what other steps should I take in diagnosing the root of my computers issues? I have cut programs running to a minimum and issues persist. Apologies for my lack of expertise, looking for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

For two hard drives to go bad within two months is unlikely a hardware issue. Here is some advice:

1) go to Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program. Now remove programs you don't use or have installed and don't need. Chances are your computer came preloaded with a bunch of programs from the factory that are useless or trial.

2) download, install and run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/). Don't agree to install any other software. After cleaning, go to Tools -> Startup. This will list all the application that start up with your computer. Disable to ones you don't want to start. Pick another tab and do same thing. Now if you computer starts to act wacky, re-enable these to determine which one it needs. Careful with this program, you could do some damage to your computer.

3) download, install and run [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/)

Once you are done with these applications you can keep them and run them from time to time to clean your machine or uninstall them using the 1st method.

4) Scan your computer for virus.

Comment: I uninstalled all useless/trail programs when I first received the computer, I have already run CCleaner to limit applications that start up with my computer, I have already run a malware program recommended by the IT department at the school I work at. None of these had any significant impact on speed. Any other suggestions? Thank you for your response

Comment: Old school advice, start command prompt with admin privileges. Type "chkdsk c: /f /r". Respond Y to prompt. Reboot. Check disk will take time. After reboot check event logs for results. If any bad blocks are detected you've got a bad HD. If results are good, HD is good.

Comment: So I did that, I restarted and the check disk began. When it got to 11% it froze there for 4 hours. I finally shut the computer down because nothing was happening, no indication it was every going to start going again. I then had numerous crashes while booting until I finally got it to start booting again fine. What is the inability to check the disk indicative of?

Comment: Your HD is starting to fail. If still under warranty get it replaced. Now is the time to back up.

Comment: Unfortunately just a few weeks after warranty ended, do you have any advice or threads you can direct me to in order to identify what hard drives will fit into my mother board?

Comment: Here is a article from Tom's Hardware page.http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2584528/ssd-lenovo-y510p.html

Comment: Also, this guys goes through how to remove HD from your model of laptop.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuCMbg0g_pg